# Need strategy to preserve partition leaders on Kafka rolling restart

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have a kafka cluster with brokers distributed as containers to the data nodes by the nomad orchestrator.

Whenever I try to run a container, or exec into a container, I get an error like the following:

```
root@ip-172-25-1-58:~# docker exec -it 4188ccb7f4a5 bash
rpc error: code = 5 desc = open /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd/4188ccb7f4a5b45eec4d3254ad31db5308ad016982d8595acfe2d1b92f017f2f/0dab278911acc60fb7af41b6e0d8377194785b2853b3ca6da7a2bcf030110522/shim-log.json: no such file or directory
```

This seems to be a common issue, and occurred eventually on every one of the clusters' nodes.  It was simple to restart dockerd on the non-data nodes because other than some brief interruptions, there weren't any other consequences.

However, I am concerned that doing so on each of my data nodes-- one at a time-- would result in the Kafka partition leaders being screwed up.

Ideas to avoid, fix, or mitigate this would be greatly appreciated.  Ideally, I would like to keep the Kafka cluster up, but would be interested in solutions that didn't meet this requirement also.

Also very interested if there is a way to get docker to right itself without restarting containerd.

Kafka container is based off of confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.1.1

```
root@ip-172-25-1-58:~# docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.27 (downgraded from 1.38)
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        e68fc7a
 Built:             Fri Jan 25 14:33:54 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          17.03.2-ce
  API version:      1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.6.2
  Git commit:       f5ec1e2
  Built:            Thu Jul  5 23:07:48 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "would result in the Kafka partition leaders being screwed up"? Kafka handles rolling restarts very well

Comment: @MickaelMaison At the moment the partition leaders are evenly distributed for a given topic among their assigned brokers.  From my limited understanding, bringing down a broker will cause the leadership of partitions for which it was a leader to be redistributed to the remaining brokers.  At the very least wouldn't this mean that the last broker to be restarted will not be a leader of any partitions?  The only way I can think to remedy is to export the partitions assignments for every topic, and then run it after the rolling restart is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka handles rolling restart very well.

On creation, Kafka will also try to distribute leaders as much as possible across the cluster to ensure "leader balance". Also the broker that is the initial leader becomes the preferred leader.

By default, Kafka will try to elect preferred leaders when possible.

So if you roll your cluster, while it's rolling, leaders may not be ideally balanced but once the rolling has completed, Kafka should re-elect preferred leaders and the cluster should return to a balance state.